# JavaScript foreach sends everything at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in javascript programming so i experienced a problem while i was trying to make a script.
I have an textarea and a button that calls the function " test() "
In the textarea, I'm going to insert Links and I am going to use AJAX to post each link and get a response from the callback.

I can do all this no problem, by using jquery  function .each or for(i=0;i

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("qitu").innerHTML = 'Checking Started...';
    var mylines = $("#ti").val().split("\n");

    for(i=0;i<mylines.length;i++) {
        if(mylines[i] != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type:       "POST",
                url:        "callback.php",
                data: { checklink : mylines[i] },
                 beforeSend: function() {
                    document.getElementById("qitu").innerHTML = 'Checking ' + mylines[i];
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    i++;
                    if(result.status == 'invalid') {

                    } else {

                    }
                 },

                 complete: function() {
                    document.getElementById("qitu").innerHTML = 'Checking is done';
                 }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

So is there any recommendations ?

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous**. It takes almost no time to *start* a request, but they take some time to complete.

Comment: I can recommend using the async library for tasks like this: https://github.com/caolan/async. Promises might also be worth looking into.

Comment: @Pointy  thats what i want, i dont want the second request to start without the last one being completed ?

Comment: @David Would there be any other way without having to install that ?

Comment: @Fokker then you have to start the second request in the "success" or "complete" callback from the first one.

Comment: oh, good idea, so i would just remove the for() fucntion and start from line 0 which is the first line and then i would increase it everytime in the success or complete, thanks I hope this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed this by calling the function on complete and proceeding with the next line by keeping record of the number of lines after each error or success

```
function other(n,b,g) {

document.getElementById("qitu").innerHTML = 'Checking Started...';
var mylines = $("#ti").val().split("\n");
var good = 0;
var bad = 0;
var i = 0;
var remaining = mylines.length;
    if(mylines[n] != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            url:        "class.uploader.php",
            data: { mydata : mylines[n] },
             beforeSend: function() {
                // my loading function
             },
             success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                if(result.status == 'invalid') {
                    b++;
                    document.getElementById("bad").innerHTML = b;

                } else {
                    g++;
                    document.getElementById("good").innerHTML = g;
                    document.getElementById("mythings").innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + result.thing + '</td><td>' + result.code + '</td></tr>';
                }
             },
             complete: function() {
                 n++;
                 if(n < mylines.length) {
                    other(n,b,g);
                 }
                 remaining -= n;
                 document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = remaining;
                if(remaining == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("qitu").innerHTML = 'Checking is done';
                }

             }
        });
    }
```

}

I got the idea from a guy who commented on this page and i hope this helped someone.